# C++ polymorphism: going from base class to derived class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
class A{};

class B : A{};

void func(A* p)
{

      B* p2 = p; // Error

}
```

Comment: That's just not how inheritance works. Is every animal a dog? What's the problem?

Comment: Well, `B` is certainly not an `A`, since the inheritance is private. There is no polymorphism here.

Comment: @juanchopanza: It is, but only inside the definition of B.

Comment: Seriously, question consisting only of piece of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has several oddities.

1. You use private inheritance. In private inheritance you will not be able to convert to a derived class ever when you are not inside the class scope itself.
2. Even if you would inherit publicly, you will need at least one virtual function (and that should be the destructor) in the base class to use `dynamic_cast`.
3. Chances are you are doing something wrong when you need a lot of down-casts. You should probably rethink your design or usage of the provided API.

Typically, things would look like this:

```
class A { 
public:
  virtual ~A() {}
};


class Derived : public A {

};

void func(A* a) {
  if(Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(a)) {
    // yeah, a is of type derived
  } else {
    // a is not of type Derived 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`is-a` relationship is implemented by `public` inheritance. as you are inheriting it `private`ly this is `association` relationship which is **not** `is-a`. so `B` is not an `A`. So you cannot store `A` in `B` or `A` cannot become an `B`

and `dynamic_cast` will not work as **source type is not polymorphic**
neither would `static_cast` work as **‘A’ is an inaccessible base of ‘B’**

To make an `is-a` relationship you need to do `class B: public A{}`

Answer (score -1):

For classes private inheritance is used by default.